# Integer domains and fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

While studying algebra I came across the following problematic: $F$ fields and $R\ne\emptyset$ a subring of $F$, then $R$ is an integer domain, moreover it was supposed that $1_F\in R$, I did not understand the reason for this assumption.

After having reasoned I arrived at the following conclusion: if $F$ is a field and $R$ a subring of $F$ it is beyond question that $R$ is a integer domain. Now, same author when they define a integer domain they do not insist on the fact that the ring must be unitary, then in this case if we are interested having a unity in $R$ we have to suppose that $1_F\in R$. However, if for us an integer domain is a commutative ring with unity that has no zero divisors, then necessarily $1_R=1_F$, otherwise we can prove that $1_R$ is a zero divisor in $F$, but this is impossible, because $F$ is a field.

It's correct? Thanks!

Comment: $1_F=1_F1_R=1_R$ in $R$ is all you need to show that $1_R=1_F$.

Comment: The reason I guess for the assumption $1_F \in R$ is  the choice of the definition of an `Integral domain' as a  non zero ring with identity.

Comment: @R.C.Cowsikthanks for your ansewer. But, if we consider $R\subseteq F$, when $R$ is an integer domain and $F$ is a field, that is a commutative ring with unity without zero divisors, then necessarily $1_R=1_F$, otherwise $1_R$ it would be a divisor of the zero of $F$. Right?